# Creation Aggregate Using Value Object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Can value object create an aggregate?
i think if a value object can reference to another aggregate root it will can create another aggregate.

Comment: I see a VO as a very simple value-type object. It can't exist outside of an entity and I can't imagine a single ubiquitous language (read requirement) that'll translate to the VO containing a factory.

Can you give an example/details of what your requirement is?

Comment: thanks   for your  guide  i think  creating  a aggregate on value object is nonsense.

Comment: @MohammadMoahammad Did you check my answer? Did you have a use case in mind for a value object acting as a factory?

Answer (score 0):

There's no design rule that I know of which discourages to place a factory method for ARs on a VO. I see it the same as having a factory method on an AR to create another AR.

However, if the creation process becomes complex enough to require external dependencies then a VO may not good home for that factory method.

In that case it may be better to pass the VO as a dependency to the creation process living in a dedicated factory class.